# Message format rosbridge v2.0

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have to publish on topic \cmd_vel a message:'{"linear":{"x":1,"y":0,"z":0}, "angular":{"x":0,"y":0,"z":0}}', of the type geometry_msgs/Twist using rosbridge v2.0. I have written:
connection = new ros.Connection("ws://localhost:9090");
connection.publish('/cmd_vel', 'geometry_msgs/Twist', '{"linear":{"x":1,"y":0,"z":0}, "angular":{"x":0,"y":0,"z":0}}');
But the format message is for rosbridge v1.0.
What I can write to publish the same message in the correct format of rosbridge v2.0?
Thanks a lot!
Chiara

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54214/message-format-rosbridge-v2.0/) by [chiara300689](https://answers.ros.org/users/4131/chiara300689/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could refer to the following rosjs example,
https://github.com/RobotWebTools/keyboardteleopjs/blob/groovy-devel/keyboardteleop.js

---

Originally posted by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) with karma: 393 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0